# Angular Universal - On "npm run dev:ssr" facing node_module issue

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, package.json

I installed "Angular Universal" in my project, which originally ran on Angular version 11. Upon attempting to execute "npm run dev:ssr," I encountered an issue within the "node_modules > express-serve-static-core" directory. Despite attempting to address the problem by modifying TypeScript and Angular CLI configurations, there was no improvement. I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this matter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of nodejs you use with npm run dev:ssr?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling the packages?

Comment: @НикитаСереда I am using NVM for node switch and trying to run the project in 11.0.9, 11.2.0, 14. But no use.

Comment: @EKnot Yes, already done.